# Marklogic xquery gives different result on different servers

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have an XML file, a query and two servers.

I loaded the xml file into both using mlcp ad put attribute range indexes on where I think they are needed.

Our dev server acts as I expected, but the TEST server gives back only the first map element in the document. Checked all db setting, reloaded the docs, re-indexed both servers no result...

The document looks like this:

```
<geo version="0.3" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/geo-mapping">
  <meta-data>
    <!--Generated by DIKW for NetwerkVSP STTip-->
    <dateCreated>2014-06-27 15:17:17.643318</dateCreated>
  </meta-data>
  <map ppc4_id="3902" wijk_id="390213">
    <bruto>196</bruto>
    <stickers>19</stickers>
    <netto>177</netto>
    <aktief>J</aktief>
  </map>
  <map ppc4_id="3902" wijk_id="3902B01">
    <bruto>36</bruto>
    <stickers>3</stickers>
    <netto>33</netto>
    <aktief>J</aktief>
  </map>
  <map ppc4_id="3902" wijk_id="3902K01">
    <bruto>245</bruto>
    <stickers>44</stickers>
    <netto>201</netto>
    <aktief>J</aktief>
  </map>
  <map ppc4_id="3903" wijk_id="390301">
    <bruto>256</bruto>
    <stickers>37</stickers>
    <netto>219</netto>
    <aktief>J</aktief>
  </map>
```

with roughly another 35000 map elements following.

The XQuery intents to find maps with certain ppc4_id or wijk_id attributes like so:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace gm = "http://www.nvsp.nl/geo-mapping";

let $p4_id := "6626"
let $wijk_id := "662601"
let $uri := '/data/map/geo-mapping.xml'

(: setup query:)
let $q2 := cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("gm:map"), xs:QName("ppc4_id"), $p4_id)
let $q3 := cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("gm:map"), xs:QName("wijk_id"), $wijk_id)

(: return map with wijk_id from geo:)
let $maps := cts:search(//gm:map,$q2,("unfiltered"))

return $maps
```

Now the DEV server finds appropriate results like:

```
<map ppc4_id="6626" wijk_id="662601" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/geo-mapping">
<bruto>220</bruto>
<stickers>11</stickers>
<netto>209</netto>
<aktief>J</aktief>
</map>
element 
<map ppc4_id="6626" wijk_id="662602" xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/geo-mapping">
<bruto>198</bruto>
<stickers>13</stickers>
<netto>185</netto>
<aktief>J</aktief>
</map>
... more map elements ...
```

But the TEST server gives back **only the first** map element from the doc! No matter what id I ask for.

The scary part is that is does not complain or give an error but gives back a wrong answer?

Comment: well, I am not sure we can help you here. If indeed everything is identical as you say it is, then of course you should get back the same result (i.e. it is a bug in ML). If there simply is not everything identical, it is quite impossible to tell from your description.

Comment: tx dirkk for response, question remains how can it be a cts:search gives back the first element in a doc when it searches on an attribute id ...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - I think this boils down to "I'm running the same query on two different clusters that should be the same, but I'm seeing different results. Are there any tools that will show me why the results are different?" I'd edit to that effect, but it would be a pretty radical change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm observing the same with 7.0-2.3. What you effectively see happening is that the unfiltered search returns the fragment for the entire geo-mapping document. And for some reason the searchable expression is returning just the first map element within it on your test server. Maybe there is a version difference?

What you observe is caused by the 'unfiltered' option. Run filtered and it will work fine without any extra indexes. From the looks of it adding an attribute range index doesn't help, nor enabling positions, though I thought that should. Maybe Mike's suggestions can help investigate what is happening there.

What does help is add a fragment root for the map element. But I wouldn't recommend using fragmentation on such a large document. Split the geo-mapping into separate map documents. That makes getting accurate estimates much easier..

HTH!

Comment: Yes, the difference between the two systems could be the fragment root or fragment parent configuration. Index entries point to fragments, so that could explain the different query results.

Comment: ok grtjn the 'filtered' options solves my problem, thx. Also on the TST server I did not have the fragment root setup. So reading the docs on http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search I can now see how this result ended up... unfiltered it gave back 'candidate' results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several tools to figure out what a query is doing. In this case https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan and https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:query-trace should help.

You could also try https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:query-meters but it's generally more useful for performance analysis.

Also it's often useful to https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:describe your results. Sometimes that reveals subtleties that don't show up in the XML or browser rendering.